# Sound only come through screen. Force-reboot on alsa needed to have sound on speaker

Tags: linux-mint, startup, pulseaudio, alsa

I am running Mint 19.3.

The sound on my computer comes from my screen (e.g. via the display port) instead of the speaker which is connected via jack.

I solved the problem doing a `sudo alsa force-reload`: after that, I have sound on my speaker. Now I would like to permanently have a solution without retyping the command at each startup.

I added `alsa force-reload` to my `/etc/rc.local`, but it doesn't work.

**How can I launch this command at each startup (knowing that it requires `sudo`)? Or, is there another solution to fix `alsa` ?**

Here are my alsa log, using `alsinfo.sh` just [after startup](https://pastebin.com/t8LjiX4f), and just [after force-rebooting alsa](https://pastebin.com/aZN0nPux)

Also, my `/var/log/syslog` file always contains these three lines on alsa:

```
Apr 10 13:11:15 GLaDOS pulseaudio[3206]: [alsa-sink-ALC1220 Analog] alsa-sink.c: ALSA woke us up to write new data to the device, but there was actually nothing to write.
Apr 10 13:11:15 GLaDOS pulseaudio[3206]: [alsa-sink-ALC1220 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
Apr 10 13:11:15 GLaDOS pulseaudio[3206]: [alsa-sink-ALC1220 Analog] alsa-sink.c: We were woken up with POLLOUT set -- however a subsequent snd_pcm_avail() returned 0 or another value < min_avail.
```

Answer (score 0):

In MATE version there is a control 'mate-volume-control' accessible from the menu or Control center' or typed in terminal.
There there is (normally) a box listing the outputs availlable, under the tab 
 'Hardware' (label translated from FR version 'Matériel' )  and  'Output' ('Sortie')

[image: mate-volume-control]

Comment: Yes I've checked that. I'm using cinnamon version, there is also a 'sound' panel in the system configuration.  However, just after startup, it indicates only one output ("DisplayPort 3 HDA Nvidia", i.e. the screen speakers). After `alsa force-reload`, it indicates three output : screen speaker, motherboard jack (the one I want to use) and the tower front panel jack (that I use sometimes for headset), and I can correctly switch between them

Comment: Well, sorry.  I cannot suggest more, only made some search with google with the information of sound card ('hardinfo' or 'inxi -A' ) and Mint version.  Good luck  !